# What's the best way to mirror a value across two ActiveRecord rows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `user#show` view and also a `membership#show` view.

The `users#show` view has the path

```
/users/john-mcenroe
```

The `membership#show` view will have the path

```
/org-name/memberships/john-mcenroe
```

*in other words, the user#show and org#show view both have identical slugs*

For the sake of lookup speed I assume the best thing to do is to mirror the slug column from user on the membership model too. To that end I've created a user observer that updates the membership whenever the user's slug changes.

Is an observer the best way to echo de-normalised data across DB tables? Is there a native rails way to do this instead (an equivalent to counter_cache for isntance)?

Answer (score 0):

If there's an association between user and membership, then you can can use the "delegate" method.

For example:

```
class Membership
    belongs_to :user
    delegate :slug, :to => :user
end
```

In this case, the "slug" is stored on the user model, and you don't need to copy the data to the membership model.

Comment: This doesn't really help. It still executes `user.slug` which executes the query I believe the OP is trying to avoid